# How do I declare a XDocument namespace globally in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML file and it contains a namespace. Every time I have to read or create a new `XElement`, I have to do the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XNamespace xNamespace = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement(xNamespace + "element"));
xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement(xNamespace + "anotherElement"));
```

So, every time I am having to add the `xNamespace` before the `XElement` name. Is there a way to globally declare the `xNamespace` for that `XDocument`, so that I don't have to write `(xNamespace + "element")` every time?

Comment: I don't believe such thing exists as XElement needs to have namespace but knows nothing about its parent when create that way... Side note: consider using XML serialization instead of building XML this way.

Comment: If you are required to have a namespace then you must have xNamespace before each element.  It may not be needed in the child if the parent has the same namespace.  In your case I would have a root element : XElement root = doc.Root; root.Add(new XElement(xNamespace + "element"));

Comment: No, but `XElement` has a property `Document` so you could add an extension method to do this as long as the parent has already been added to an `XDocument`, see e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3sndVm.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: All the answers made sense so yes, I got to learn something new :)